# Creating an app on Heroku with Django and NPM

Tags: django, heroku, coffeescript, npm

I'm writing a Django app that includes some CoffeeScript in it.  To allow for this I'm using django-compressor which compiles the CoffeeScript to JS before the app is launched.  django-compressor requires that NPM is installed on the machine to compile the CoffeeScript.

Now I want to deploy this app on Heroku.  I can't put npm in my `requirements.txt` so I am wondering how I can get npm on the Heroku server?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Note**: The [multi buildpack](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) is a much nicer way to accomplish this these days :)

---

I've created a fork of the official Python heroku buildpack that allows an optional `npm_requirements.txt` for installing such dependencies.

I am now using coffeescript and less-css with django-compressor on heroku :)

https://github.com/jiaaro/heroku-buildpack-django

**Edit**: To switch to my buildback from the standard buildpack:

1. use the `heroku` command line app to set the `BUILDPACK_URL` environment variable:

   ```
   heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/jiaaro/heroku-buildpack-django.git
   ```

Comment: Wow, this is great!  Were you having the same issue?

Comment: @alexis yup - I may add support for gems too, but at the moment I don't need any :)

Comment: thanks.  I used your buildpack and it worked perfectly.  Thanks very much!! I really appreciate it an I'm sure a lot of other people will find it helpful as well!

Comment: Hello!  I liked the buildpack pack so much the first time I am building another project with it!  However, when I start the app, it crashes.  I'm looking in the logs and it says `ImportError: No module named site`.  I have `'django.contrib.sites'` in `INSTALLED_APPS` and `SITE_ID = 1` a la http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596710/site-module-not-found-when-deploying-to-heroku.  I then made a Hello World type app but got the same error.  Do you know what might be causing this?  Did something on heroku's side change?

Comment: Fewwww, I think if `python $PROJECT/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:\$PORT --noreload` is changed to `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:\$PORT --noreload` in `bin\release` things will be good!  Looks like Heroku changed something because your stuff was working before.  I added a Procfile to  do this and things are starting to not throw errors :)  Also, updating a repository with the buildpack doesn't work.  Before I was doing `$ heroku create` then updating then `heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=http://github.com/jiaaro/heroku-buildpack-django.git`.  But this wasn't working.

Comment: To make things work it seem like it has to be done like this `heroku create --stack cedar --buildpack http://github.com/jiaaro/heroku-buildpack-django.git`  Thanks again for the great code Jiaaro.  Hope this helps for other people or if you would be kind enough to update it :)

Comment: Perhaps this answer precedes the multi buildback, but that is most certainly a better approach.

Comment: @YanivAknin yes, I would advice the multi build pack, and in fact, that's the approach I now use

Answer (score 34):

If you want to avoid maintaining a custom buildpack, you can use the [multi buildpack](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi).

Using the multi buildpack is super simple:

1. Run `heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git`
2. Create a .buildpacks file in the root of your repository with two lines:
   `https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git`
   `https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git`
3. Create a [package.json](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs#packagejson) file with your npm dependencies.
4. Run `npm install`

Comment: Heroku now supports multi-buildpacks officially: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own [buildpack](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks), that mix [nodejs buildbpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs) and [python buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python). Or compile your CoffeeScript on your machine and put it on S3.

Answer (score 3):

I found this question in Google while solving the same problem for myself.
I merged two official buildpacks (python and nodejs), so now one can have Django project with standard npm-description file `package.json` by running this command:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/podshumok/heroku-buildpack-python
```

This solution differs from Jiaaro's one in the following:

- it is based on the newer (dec 12) versions of buildpacks (for example, it runs collectstatic on deployment)
- you need correct `package.json` file (at least name and version of your product should be specified in this file)
- npm dependencies should be listed in `package.json`

Comment: Worked like a champ! +1 for avoiding custom buildpacks as Jiaaro's no longer seems to work per my experience and Alex-zak's.

Answer (score 3):

@Jiaaro 's solution didn't work for me... Causes some weird error... /:

```
File "almalinks/manage.py", line 8, in <module>
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Was too tired to deal with it, so I looked around and I found this nifty resource:
[- The heroku-django cookbook](https://github.com/nigma/heroku-django-cookbook)

They explain how you can add your own scripts that hook into heroku's default buildpacks.
Worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Things have changed in Heroku land**

There is no need for multi build packs, .builpack files, or custom build packs.  Simply add the required official heroku build packs to your heroku app and they will execute in the order entered.  Use the index option to reorder them as required.

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs -a your_app_name
```

There is also no need for, gunt tasks, apps like django-bower, or other specialized tools that take up server resources and slow build time.

**You can check out my tutorial on how to seamlessly integrate Django + Bower + Heroku [here](https://arctelix.wordpress.com/2016/09/29/configuring-django-bower-heroku-is-so-simple-your-probably-doing-it-wrong/).**