# Install NPM (Node Package Manager) with pip?

Tags: heroku, coffeescript, pip, npm

I'm on Heroku and I would like to get NPM installed for a Django application.  Is it possible to get npm installed using pip with the `requirements.txt` file?

Answer (score 2):

No. `pip` installs python packages.

Comment: Do you really think it is impossible to npm via pip. I think the problem is turing complete. Yes, it does not work with one command at the moment. But ... is it impossible?

Answer (score 1):

While "no" is the direct answer to your question, this is probably more helpful to you:

[Creating an app on Heroku with Django and NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381196/creating-an-app-on-heroku-with-django-and-npm)